# What does SUMIFS mean and what is meaning of the expression given below

Tags: excel, ms-office

Can you please tell me what the below expression mean? I am not that friendly with MS-Excel.

```
=SUMIFS(
    $sheet1.E:E,
    $sheet1.A:A,
    $sheet2.C7,
    $sheet1.B:B,
    $sheet2.D8,
    $sheet1.C:C,
    $sheet2.I9
)
```

I googled `SUMIFS`. Everybody has given syntax like `=SUMIFS($sheet1.E1:G1,$sheet2.A1:C1,......)`.

Comment: Have you looked it up? I suspect this would be well documented.

Comment: I looked up columns of the respective sheets but didn't understand what that mean.

Comment: No, the documentation for the function. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMIF will conditionally add values in the first column.

The conditions for adding are specified in the other parts of the formula.
Let us simplify your formula to what I have written. Then

Col E is where values to be added are located.
Col A is condition col 1, used to find if we will add the value or not.
Cell C7 is criteria for col A. If the value in C7 matches the *n*th cell of column A on Sheet 1, excel will **add the *n*th cell of column E** to the total.

```
=SUMIFS(
    $sheet1.E:E, 
    $sheet1.A:A, //criteria range 1
    $sheet2.C7,  //criteria 1

)
```

If the *n*th cell in the criteria range matches with the criteria, then the nth cell of the sum range is added to the total.

Like this, we can have many criteria ranges and criterias. Only if all of them are satisfied will the value in the sum range be added. In your formula, you have three different citeria ranges and criterias.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically adding everything in column E of sheet 1, *if*

- in column A of sheet 1, you have same value as cell C7 of sheet2
- in column B of sheet 1, you have same value as cell D8 of sheet2, etc.

It is basically adding some values based on multiple criteria.